# Swift Firebase linking two nodes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app and when a user creates an account it generates a uid for that user.

When the user continues to use the app and creates a card it will create a separate node under "cards" and generate a unique id for that card with a name and type of card. This is how I have done it

```
 let card = ref.child("cards").childByAutoId()

card.setValue(["nickname": finalNickname, "type": finalType])
```

I am trying to link the nodes, I have been told to not put everything under one tree but to flatten it and have them be separate and then just link it.

This is what I have tried to do, with no success

```
 ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("cards").child(card).setValue(true)
```

The problem that I am getting is that the .child(...) wants a String, and card is a FIRDatabaseReference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `card` variable is a [`FIRDatabaseReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference). You're looking to [get the key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#key) from it, so `card.key`:

```
ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("cards").child(card.key).setValue(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this?

```
         ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).child("cards").childByAutoId().setValue(["nickname": finalNickname, "type": finalType])
```

It is not really clear what you are exactly trying to do, could you provide more information